# Нужна ли запятая перед словом "какие"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

"...а также узнаете какие товары не пользуются спросом".

Нужна ли запятая перед словом "какие"?

Comment: Указанная запятая нужна.

Answer (score 2):

***...а также узнаете, какие товары не пользуются спросом.***

Это фрагмент сложноподчиненного предложения. Запятая перед словом ***какие*** нужна.

> *Я уже и не вспом­ню, какие собы­тия при­влек­ли все­об­щее внимание.*
>
> *Нельзя же одно­му видеть, дышать здесь и так уйти, и люди не будут знать, какая быва­ет на зем­ле кра­со­та* (В. Солоухин).

Источник: [**Запятая перед словом «КАКОЙ»**](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/pered-kakoi-zapyataya.html)